# MySQL phpMyAdmin build JOIN's from foreign keys

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using LAMP and maintain MySQl via phpMyAdmin.  I am tired of typing out JOIN's every time i want to build a multitable query on InnoDB tables.

Does anyone know of some feature, plugin, approach or resource to generate JOIN statements from foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a query that builds `JOIN` statements from all foreign keys:

```
CREATE VIEW Joins_All AS 
SELECT 
    concat(" JOIN ",TABLE_NAME," ON ",
    TABLE_NAME,".",COLUMN_NAME," = ",
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,".", REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME) 
    AS myJoin 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
  WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL 

UNION

SELECT  
    concat(" JOIN ",REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME," ON ",
    TABLE_NAME,".",COLUMN_NAME," = ",
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,".", REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME) 
    AS myJoin 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
  WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL 

ORDER BY myJoin  ASC
```

it generates something like this:

> JOIN Area ON Area_Tare.Id_Area = Area.Id_Area
>
> JOIN Area_Tare ON Area_Tare.Id_Area = Area.Id_Area
>
> JOIN Insect ON Insect.Id_Insect_Class = Insect_Class.Id_Insect_Class
>
> JOIN Insect ON Insect_Insumo_Formula_Ingredient.Id_Insect = Insect.Id_Insect

I saved this file and copy/paste the appropriate lines qhen i need them OR i filter the view with the names of the desired tables

This could easily be adapted (which i wont do at this time) in php to create a GUI query builder based on foreign keys.  Anyone who decides to do so, please feel free to use / adapt this code.

Comment: additionally, in your where clause, you can filter tables to get only the relationships that you want.  :)